# How to clone a div easily?

Tags: javascript

Hello I would like to copy or clone my div six times I found this way to do it but I was wondering if there is another way to do it more easily with less code?
code
http://jsfiddle.net/zvdekh8p/4/

html

```
<div id="test">Hello World</div>
```

javascript

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("test");

document.body.appendChild(myDiv.cloneNode(true));
document.body.appendChild(myDiv.cloneNode(true));
document.body.appendChild(myDiv.cloneNode(true));
document.body.appendChild(myDiv.cloneNode(true));
document.body.appendChild(myDiv.cloneNode(true));
document.body.appendChild(myDiv.cloneNode(true));
```

Comment: with a loop it would take 2 lines instead of 6, but I don't get the purpose.

Comment: "thanks pierre i will do it"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clone a Div Multiple Times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088724/clone-a-div-multiple-times)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("test");

for(var i=0; i < 6; i++) {
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv.cloneNode(true));
}
```